# *ngFor does not iterate the array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created an array of posts that has as propreties title & content
when I use  ***ngFor** to display it nothing is displayed

this is the code of ts file of the component

```
posts = [

{
  title: 'first',
  content: '...'
},

{
  title: 'second',
  content: '...'
}

]
```

and this line of code is in the global view **app.component.html**

```
<app-mon-post *ngFor="let post of posts">{{ post.title }} </app-mon-post>
```

Comment: what does the app-mon-post template look like? can you maybe provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: @sevic the template is empty

Comment: Have you tried <a> {{post.title}} </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the issue is not caused by the `*ngFor` directive, but by the `<app-mon-post>` element. Please try to use standard HTML-tags to test the loop:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts">{{ post.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Please note that the content of custom elements such as `<app-mon-post>` is only visible if either:

- the element is unknown to the browser
- the element has some code to display it. In an Angular component the content is typically referenced by using an `@ContentChild` input variable.